# Incomplete data from a stream

Tags: java, process, stream, io, inputstream

I am reading data from a process stream. Basically, I am running the process using Runtime.exec API and getting the process input stream.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
process = rt.exec("C:/cygwin/home/grec.exe");
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
```

I am then collecting the output of the process as --

```
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(is);         
            char[] ls = new char[s.available()];
            ls.read(ls);
            String output = new String(ls);
```

However when I am printing the string output, I am getting --

```
  break [loc]     Add a breakpoint at [file:]line or template
  callflow [val]  Enable call flow tracing
  next            Execute the over instruction, stepping over calls
  over            Execute the current instruction hierarchy
```

But the actual output is --

```
  break [loc]     Add a breakpoint at [file:]line or template
  callflow [val]  Enable call flow tracing 
  next            Execute the over instruction, stepping over calls
  over            Execute the current instruction hierarchy
  print <xpath>   Print the value of an XPath expression
 profile [val]   Turn profiler on or off
 reload          Reload the script contents
 run             Restart the script
 step            Execute the next instruction, stepping into calls
 verbose         Turn on verbose (-v) output logging
 where           Show the backtrace of template calls
 quit            Quit debugger
```

That is, a part of the output gets truncated, but no exception is thrown by the code. I have tried increasing the BufferedReader size and also increasing the size of the array ls.I am at a loss to find the cause of this behavior. Any hints or pointers on what might be the cause of this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `s` in your code example? And maybe I overlooked something, but how about: `OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream(); BufferedReader bufferedOut = new BufferedReader(out); `

Comment: Actually Im doing exactly the same thing. And this is what Im doing--

Comment: Here actually s stands for the InputStream. That is --InputStream s = process.getInputStream();

Comment: Why not use `in.readline()`? Why are you creating char array?

Answer (score 1):

You are making the mistake of assuming that `available()` tells you how many bytes / characters are actually available.  In fact, it tell you that *at least* that many are available ... and it might be wrong because it is an estimate.

Then you are compounding the problem by accessing the `InputStream` after you've wrapped it in a `BufferedReader`.  So instead of getting the number of *characters* that can be read from the reader, you are getting the number of available *bytes* that haven't yet been read into the buffer yet.

---

You are probably better off simply reading from the `BufferedReader` a line at a time using `readLine()`.

Comment: Hello Stephen,  Thanks for the clarification. Now I understand the mistake in my code. I have tried using the BufferedReader.readLine API in my code. However, here I am facing another problem. My process output is -- sdb: The SLAX Debugger (version 0.9.6)
Type 'help' for help
(sdb)

Comment: The last line is <sdb>. In this case, the readLine call just hangs without giving any exception.

Comment: The process output always contains <sdb> as the final putput. It gets all the lines correctly but always hangs at the lastline and does not return from the last call to readLine.

Comment: The reason is that the last line doesn't have a newline (yet).  If you want to be able to deal with that, you'll need to a character at a time, and deal with the "prompt" appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs..really appreciate. But can you explain this a bit more elaborately, with code. How do I handle the last line without causing the readLine to hang. Also, the process out may vary with respect to the number of lines..so how do I handle this in a generic manner--

Comment: I am using this code--BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println("Thread this thsi "+line);            
            
            output=output+"\n"+line;
            //System.out.println(in.ready());
            
            
            }

Comment: @user496934 - if you have to deal with partial lines, you can't use `readLine()`.  You have to read (and process) one character at a time using `read()`.

Comment: Thanks Stephen..Really appreciate your help in this. And now iv managed to get over this problem by doing some tweak in the code. But now Im facing another problem. In once scenario, the process emits some xml as out put like --

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
Source<junos-output>
security  {
       
        zones {
                security-zone
                        addre

                        }
                
}
</junos-output><local-variabl
$destAdd = ;
$addName = ;
$ipAdd = 172.168.1.2;
$serviceN = "junos-ftp";
$zone = "Trust";
$destAddress = "secure_zone";
$permit = permit;
$src = source;
$count = count;
$log = session-init;
$val = ;
</local-variables>
Script exited normally.
(sdb)

Comment: In this case, I am seeing that readLine is not able to get any output..infact the first call to readLine just hangs indefinately.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to process all information and read till the end of the stream.

Inputstream.available() does not do what you expected:

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream **without blocking** by the next invocation of a method for this input stream.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29